# jquery addClass and removeClass slow in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

I'm creating an app to monitor nodes on a cluster and this is an example of the visual state. Each small box in the grid represents a node and currently, when hovering over one node, the rest in that respective rack (grid) fadeout.

Here is the link via photobucket since I can't insert images due to my minimal reputation:
[visual state](http://s1296.photobucket.com/user/alex_ramos12/media/visual1_zps23fe466c.png.html?sort=3&o=0)

In Chrome and Firefox, hovering in and out a single node will instantly fadein/out the rest of the nodes in the rack, but in IE 11 it has a noticeable lag. I know that IE's javascript engine is slower than Chrome and Firefox, but I'm throwing this out there to see if the SO community can pick apart my code and suggest better ways of doing this as I am not the greatest front end programmer. Thank you and here is snippets of my code:

from the django template (each node has `id="matrix-box-<node #>"`):

```
    <tr>
    <td id="visual-state"><b>visual state</b></td>
    <td id="matrix" colspan=5>
        {% for row in v.22 %}
            {% if v.23 == "ca" %}
                {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}
                    <div id="rack-{% widthratio forloop.counter0 4 1 %}-{{ k }}" title="rack-{% widthratio forloop.counter0 4 1 %}">
                {% endif %}
            {% elif v.23 ==  "cs" %}
                {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:8 %}
                    <div id="rack-{% widthratio forloop.counter0 8 1 %}-{{ k }}" title="rack-{% widthratio forloop.counter0 8 1 %}">
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <div class="row">
            {% for elem in row %}
                {% if elem.1 == "#49E20E" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: #00DC00;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "#0000CD" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: #0000CD;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "yellow" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: yellow;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "#E3170D" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: #E31702;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "brown" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: #6E3737;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "orange" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background:#DC7800;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "black" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: black;" title="{{ elem.0 }}"></div>
                {% elif elem.1 == "#cccccf" %}
                    <div class="node node-faded" id="matrix-box-{{ elem.0 }}-{{ k }}" style="background: #CCCCCF;border: 1px solid #CCCCCF"></div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>

       ... other code
```

from css code:

```
    .node {
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
        background: #cccccf;
        margin: 0 !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
        }

    .faded .node-faded {
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        opacity: .5;
     }

    .active {
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: #cccccf;
        margin: 0 !important;
       cursor: pointer;
       filter: alpha(opacity=100);
       opacity: 1;
     }
```

from js code:

```
    var node = null;
    var node_id = null;
    var rack = null;
    var nodes = null;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[id^=matrix-box]').on({
            mouseenter: function(){
                node = $(this);
                rack = node.parent().parent();
                rack.addClass('faded');
                node.removeClass('node-faded').addClass('active');
            },
            mouseleave: function(){
                node.removeClass('active').addClass('node-faded');
                rack.removeClass('faded');
            },
            click: function(e){

            ...other code
```

Also, any constructive criticism (albeit helpful and not malicious) is always welcome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As you gave no possibility to test, this is kind of a guessing game. What you do is the following:

```
$('[id^=matrix-box]').on({ mouseenter: function(){});
```

This adds a new event listener on each element with an id starting with `matrix-box`. Not the worst idea, but it can be slow if you have a lof of these items.

**Here is demo to validate this: http://jsfiddle.net/k3mjmdzp/3/**

A good idea to overcome performance issues is to use a [delegated event listener](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Try to rewrite your code like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#matrix').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', '[id^=matrix-box]', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

**Here you have the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k3mjmdzp/2/**

This will leave your code with having only event listeners on `$('#matrix')` and not on each child node. This is also nice if you append new items via ajax later on.

You can check for event listeners on the `event Listeners` tab in chrome developer tools.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about not being able to give you a test environment due to the cluster being on a private/secure network. I may be able to come up with a mock version. I did try what you suggested and it doesn't speed up the fading noticeably, although, the logic is sound and I am leaving the implementation using this method. I'm wondering if there is an IE specific optimization I can apply when dynamically adding/removing classes. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was more thinking of a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than an complete environment. Did you try to use native functions like [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) instead of the jQuery function?